# count of record in one table not exist in multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a station tables consider table A,table B, table C,table D;

consider these table have some production data and consider there tables as a my production stations and in each station table i have a single column status which shows the flag 1,2
and in each table there is 1 primary number which is my serial no;

the flag 1 defines "OK" product and flag 2 defines "Fail Product";

but if the product get failed in table A then it may be reworked and introduced to production table A,B & C and that can be may make flag 1 in that station.
now i want to display the product which is failed in Table A and not further processed in table B and Table C.
means I want to display the total scrap product which is not processed in any station once it is failed

I have taken the data of failed product from each station into another table 
and then i am comparing that serial no with each station table with flag 1
but not able to find exact how much count of scrap serial no's from each table

In Pseudo-SQL:

```
 Select count(serial_no)
   from table "Failedparts"
  where /* serial_no neither in table "b" nor in table "c" with status = 1 */
      ;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, an appropriate database flag and a clear explanation would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your verbal description it is a bit unclear which state you wish to query:

1. a failure on station A without subsequent production attempts ( disregarding their outcome )

or

2. a failure on station A with subsequent failures on both, station B and C

The following queries operate on the original tables according to your verbal description. It is unclear how exactly you filled table `"Failedparts"` ( your description suggests that you loaded failed attempts from each table `A`, `B`, `C` ).

Case 1. would translate into

```
    SELECT count(a.serial_no)
      FROM table_a  a
     WHERE a.status = 2
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table_b b WHERE b.serial_no = a.serial_no )
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table_c c WHERE c.serial_no = a.serial_no )
         ;
```

For case 2., use:

```
    SELECT count(a.serial_no)
      FROM table_a  a
      JOIN table_b  b ON ( b.serial_no = a.serial_no AND b.status = 2 )
      JOIN table_c  c ON ( c.serial_no = a.serial_no AND c.status = 2 )
     WHERE a.status = 2
         ;
```

(Possibly you aim at a slightly different notion, but the above queries should get you started).

Answer (score 0):

Literally as you commented in the query stub

```
Select count(serial_no)
from table "Failedparts" a
where /* serial_no neither in table "b" nor in table "c" with status = 1 */
      not exists (select 1 from table_b b where b.serial_no = a.serial_no and b.flag = 1)
      and not exists (select 1 from table_c c where c.serial_no = a.serial_no and c.flag = 1);
```

Comment: The verbal description (` failed in Table A and not further processed in table B and Table C`) could also be construed to mean 'failed on A, no attempts on B or C recorded', though. It also suggests that table `failedparts` has been fed with data from all 3 tables without giving the exact query.